# Unable to login with Facebook on iOS (SDK can't build auth URL)

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk, ios12

For no apparent reason, my fully functional app with "Login with Facebook" functionality stopped working yesterday.

I dived deep into the error and found that the auth URL can't be built for some reason internally, failing the whole process.

The problem arises from `+ (NSURL *)URLWithScheme:(NSString *)scheme host:(NSString *)host path:(NSString *)path queryParameters:(NSDictionary *)queryParameters error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)errorRef` method in `FBSDKInternalUtility` class.

In line 430, it tries to build the URL:

```
NSURL *URL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                          @"%@://%@%@%@",
                                          scheme ?: @"",
                                          host ?: @"",
                                          path ?: @"",
                                          queryString ?: @""]];
```

I've stepped through the code. `scheme`, `host`, `path`, and `queryString` are all set. Though it returns `nil` instead of a URL. I've tried calling the method with an empty query string, and it actually built the URL. For some reason, `queryString` is causing the URL to be not built correctly.

Here is the `queryString`: (I've replaced my app ID with 123456789)

`(lldb) po queryString
?auth_type=rerequest&client_id=123456789&default_audience=friends&display=touch&e2e={%22init%22%3A70747.196361124996}&fbapp_pres=1&redirect_uri=fb123456789%3A%2F%2Fauthorize%2F&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&return_scopes=true&scope=user_birthday%2Cemail%2Cuser_friends%2Cuser_photos&sdk=ios&sdk_version=4.39.0&state={%22challenge%22%3A%22yi8jE3mok79u9BheN8dzCMCviGY%253D%22%2C%220_auth_logger_id%22%3A%22329202ED-2F9B-4DBC-A191-E2C720D9779C%22%2C%22com.facebook.sdk_client_state%22%3Atrue%2C%223_method%22%3A%22sfvc_auth%22}`

What might be causing this? It was working just a few days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the same error on simulator, I examined the changes to my app in more detail. It was the latest Facebook SDK (4.39). I ran a `pod update` to update some other pods, which also updated Facebook SDK from 4.38.1 to 4.39.

I reverted back to 4.38.1 and the problem went away. In other words, **Facebook SDK 4.39 broke their own login functionality, practically rendering their own SDK useless.**

Forcing to use older version as below fixed the issue:

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.38.1'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.38.1'
```